# Installation of nagios failed due to ucf and file acls

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, php5

While installing Nagios give me this error and hence the packages left unconfigured on my server. I looked for some help but they don’t tell me the exact solution. Does any one have a fix.

```
cp: preserving permissions for '/var/lib/ucf/hashfile.7': Operation not supported dpkg: error processing php5-common (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 Setting up nagios-plugins-basic (1.4.16-1ubuntu3) ...
```

Looks like some problem with ucf.